# How to minimise iteration time with a big length of a list using itertools?

Tags: python, django, list, python-itertools

I have combined element of a list `my_list` with :

```
my_combinison = itertools.product(*my_list)
```

So it create me a list of `2614234` combined elements, and I want to verify if every element in the combinison list is a scope in an object

```
list_contries_ok = list({'cities_scope': x, 'status': 1} for x in my_combinison if City.objects.only('country_id', 'city_scope').filter(country_id=CN, city_scope=','.join(x)).prefetch_related('country_id')) 
list_contries_ko = list({'cities_scope': x, 'status': 0} for x in my_combinison if not City.objects.only('country_id', 'city_scope').filter(country_id=CN, city_scope=','.join(x)).prefetch_related('country_id'))
list_contries = list_contries_ok.append(list_contries_ko)
```

I my last list I want to have list that iterate every combinaison and say if its status `1 or 0`.

It tooks me several minutes in execution :S
Is there an other clearly way to minimise time with this huge length of a list ??

Comment: 1. Profile the code. 2. Minimise function calls. 3. Use a better algorithm. 4. Rewrite in different language.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two passes over `my_combinison` when you only need to make one:

```
def predicate(x):
    t1 = City.objects.only('country_id', 'city_scope')
    t2 = t1.filter(country_id=CN,city_scope=','.join(x))
    return 1 if t2.prefetch_related('country_id') else 0

list_countries = [ { 'cities_scope': x, 'status': predicate(x) }
                    for x in my_combinison ]
```

Define `predicate` however you like; the point is the only difference between your first two lists is whether the long expression is true (set status to 1) or false (set status to 0). You can create `list_countries` in one pass, then split it into two separate lists later if necessary (which should be much faster, since you no longer run the complicated
query for each item first.)

```
list_countries_ok = [ x for x in list_countries if x['status'] ]
list_countries_ko = [ x for x in list_countries if not x['status'] ]
```

Comment: Even with one iteration or with `predicate()`, it takes a lot of time :(

Answer (score 0):

```
list_countries_ok = [ x and list_countries.remove(x) for x in list_countries if x['status'] ]
```

Now in list_countries you will have list_countries_ko without iterating over it.